# How to populate a matrix column based on a vector of Booleans?

Tags: r, vector, indexing, boolean

I have a two column matrix, `m`.  I have a vector of Booleans `index`, generated based on the sequence within `m[,1]`.  I would like to replace some values in `m[,2]`, with values from `m[,1]` but only where the same row in `index` is `TRUE`.

I'm sure there is an good way to do this without looping, but I can't get my head around it at the moment.  I have tried many ways but failed.  Here is my code:

```
m <- matrix(nrow=20,ncol=2)
m[,2] <- 0 
m[,1] <- c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
index <- (m[,1]==Lag(m[,1])) & (m[,1]!=Lag(m[,1],2))
```

I would appreciate any insight on an elegant way to achieve the correct result.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
m[which(index),2] <- m[which(index),1]
```

gives you

```
> m
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    0    0
 [2,]    0    0
 [3,]    0    0
 [4,]    1    0
 [5,]    1    1
 [6,]    1    0
 [7,]   -1    0
 [8,]    1    0
 [9,]    1    1
[10,]    1    0
[11,]    1    0
[12,]   -1    0
[13,]   -1   -1
[14,]   -1    0
[15,]   -1    0
[16,]   -1    0
[17,]    1    0
[18,]    1    1
[19,]    1    0
[20,]    1    0
```

Note that `m[index,2]` etc. would also work if there were no `NA` values in `index`.